# Generate .ipa file in Xcode 7.2

Tags: swift, xcode7

I had created an iOS application successfully. Now I want to generate an executable file (.ipa).

I know the following steps:

1. Product
2. archive
3. save ipa file

But my archive is disabled. Any ideas?

Comment: You probably select build for simulator now. Change it to build for device. Archive will be active in that case. For Xcode7.2, there is an option ``Generic iOS Device``.

Comment: Yes, change the build device to "generic iOS device". This [link](http://www.raywenderlich.com/101790/ios-beta-testing-with-testflight-tutorial) helped me when trying to archive

Comment: How to resolve this problem ?                                                                   Code Sign error: No code signing identities found: No valid signing identities (i.e. certificate and private key pair) were found.

Comment: Any reason you're using an outdated version of Xcode?

Answer (score 0):

1.You need to connect to a real device.
2.Build not for emulator, build for real device.
3.Now you can see "archive"